# Correct way to initialise model at inference (PyTorch)

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I have trained a model with frozen feature extraction layers which was initialised as followed:

```
model = models.densenet161(pretrained=True)
for param in model.parameters():
    param.requires_grad = False
num_ftrs = model.classifier.in_features
model.classifier = torch.nn.Linear(num_ftrs,2)
```

However, at inference, I am unsure of how to load the model correctly. In a separate script I do the following:

```
model = models.densenet161(pretrained=True)
for param in model.parameters():
    param.requires_grad = False
num_ftrs = model.classifier.in_features
model.classifier = torch.nn.Linear(num_ftrs,2)
model.to(device)

# load the best model
bestmodel = get_best_model(best)
bestmodel = torch.load(bestmodel)
model.load_state_dict(bestmodel['classifier'])

# set model to evaluation mode
model.eval()
with torch.no_grad():
```

Does this look correct? Or do I set `pretrained=False` when introducing the model in my inference script?

Comment: 1. You can't train a model if you set parameters requires_grad attribute to False because it would make them untrainable. 

2. You don't need to set pretrained to True because you don't need the pretrained weights that someone else trained. What you need is to load the weights that you trained yourself. You can do that once you load your best model and set the state_dict. You can do that by model.load_state_dict(bestmodel) instead of model.load_state_dict(bestmodel['classifier']).

Comment: ok thanks, so I have a checkpoint with model_dict saved inside that checkpoint. I'm guessing this is fine as it is what is suggested in the docs